# How to determine if a Weblogic server is in Production or Development mode?

Tags: java, weblogic

I am facing a problem in detecting (from application's code) whether the server runs in Production or Development mode, as it requires different behaviors. This link looked pretty promising: http://coder-in-training.blogspot.de/2012/04/specifying-projectstage-in-jndi-with.html but the server mode defaults to Production, every time. Do you know a way to determine the Weblogic Startup Mode from java code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are connecting to the domain via a JMX connection. In your java code you can do the following:

```
MBeanServerConnection conn = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, hash).getMBeanServerConnection();
DomainRuntimeServiceMBean domainRuntimeServiceMBean = (DomainRuntimeServiceMBean) 
   MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, new ObjectName(DomainRuntimeServiceMBean.OBJECT_NAME));       
DomainMBean domainBean = domainRuntimeServiceMBean.getDomainConfiguration();
```

Once you have the `DomainMBean` it is as simple as:

```
domainBean.isProductionModeEnabled()
```

Reference the DomainMBean API here:

[DomainMBean API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e13945/weblogic/management/configuration/DomainMBean.html#isProductionModeEnabled%28%29)

This may also be a useful example:

[Connecting to a server with JMX and listing info](http://www.javamonamour.org/2012/02/listing-all-jmsserver-jmsmodules.html)